# Angular animation - поочерёдная анимация элементов на странице

Tags: angular, angular-animations

Доброго всем времени суток. Задал этот вопрос на англоязычном форуме, но что то тихо и пчёлы не жужжат.

Вот моя текущая реализация [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-a2yvjh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Должно быть следующее поведение

- все элементы скрыты
- анимируется первый элемент - анимация закончилась, элемент скрывается
- анимируется следующий элемет - анимация закончилась, элемент сохраняет состояние последнего кадра
- анимируется последний элемент - анимация закончилась, элемент сохранияет состояние последнего кадра

Текущее поведение:

- - все элементы скрыты
- анимируется первый элемент - анимация закончилась, элемент скрывается
- запускается анимация для двух последних элементов параллельно, элементы сохраняют состояние последнего кадра.

Буду прям очень рад хоть каким либо подсказкам, как это правильно настроить.
Прослушивание - Animation.start, Animation.done - не интересно, нужна реализация в нутри свойства `animation` декоратора `@Component({animation: []})`

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем за внимание - надо было просто передать тайминг задержки на последний элемент.

Конечно это не лучшее решение, но зато исключает прослушивание aniamtion.start & animation.done